# Pgadmin Docker container having an adding a default server on image creation process

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I am an error while creating a Pgadmin docker container.
I am trying to create a default server and add database connection on creation of docker container.

Please check below logs from pgadmin container.

```
Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
waiting for server to start....2023-01-26 16:43:57.062 UTC [36] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.13 on aarch64-unknown-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 11.2.1 20220219, 64-bit
2023-01-26 16:43:57.064 UTC [36] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-01-26 16:43:57.076 UTC [37] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-01-26 16:43:56 UTC
2023-01-26 16:43:57.083 UTC [36] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

2023-01-26 16:43:57.171 UTC [36] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down....2023-01-26 16:43:57.173 UTC [36] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-01-26 16:43:57.176 UTC [36] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 43) exited with exit code 1
2023-01-26 16:43:57.179 UTC [38] LOG:  shutting down
2023-01-26 16:43:57.198 UTC [36] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
```

Docker-compose file:

```
postgres:
    # image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Docker/Postgres/Dockerfile
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - 'default'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
    expose:
      - 5432
  pgadmin4:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Docker/PgAdmin/Dockerfile
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=test@test.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=test
    volumes:
      - ./Docker/PgAdmin/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
    networks:
      - 'default'
    ports:
      - 9050:80
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: wget localhost/misc/ping -q -O - > /dev/null 2>&1 || exit 1
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
```

I am using `postgres:12-alpine3.16` and `dpage/pgadmin4` images.

Can someone please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: It looks like you're not using the official postgres image. Without seeing `Docker/Postgres/Dockerfile`, we can't tell if the problem is due to an error in how you've built your container image. Can you reproduce the problem using the official image instead of your custom image?

Comment: Thanks for your response. `Docker/Postgres/Dockerfile` is having `FROM postgres:12-alpine3.16`, and `Docker/PgAdmin/Dockerfile` is having `FROM dpage/pgadmin4`. The postgres is working fine. I can ssh into the container and can  see databases. I can manually add the server on pgadmin as well.
The problem is PgAdmin is not loading the server on creation. I am attaching the server configs in the volume section as you can see above.